# What is the difference between the set and append methods of angulars HttpParams object?

Tags: javascript, angular, http

The method description for `append` is:

> Construct a new body with an appended value for the given
> parametername.

While the method description for `set` is:

> Construct a new body with a **new** value for the given parametername.

But with `append` you can set a new value for a parametername as well. Both methods create the parameter when it doesn't exist so i was wondering why there are 2 methods that pretty much do the same thing and when you should use one instead of the other.

thank you

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`HttpParams` values are array of values. When you `set` the value, it will override all the values in the array. When you `append` the value, it will push new values on the existing array.

You can check the difference like this:

```
let paramsSet = new HttpParams();
paramsSet = paramsSet.set("paramName", "set");

let paramsAppend = new HttpParams();
paramsAppend = paramsAppend.set("paramName", "append");

paramsSet = paramsSet.set("paramName", "set2");
paramsAppend = paramsAppend.append("paramName", "append2");

console.log(paramsSet.getAll("paramName"));
console.log(paramsAppend.getAll("paramName"));
```

`paramsSet` will only have `['set2']` as the value, while `paramsAppend` will have `["append", "append2"]`.

Answer (score 18):

`set` sets a unique `value` for the given `key`:

```
params.set('toto', '1').set('toto', '2') // toto=2
```

`append` appends another `value` for the given `key`:

```
params.set('toto', '1').append('toto', '2') // toto=1&toto=2
```

Answer (score 1):

If all of your parameters are unique, then you are correct the behavior will be the same; however, if you try to reuse a parameter, then the behavior will be different.

Set will ADD or OVERRIDE the existing value for that parameter.
Append will always ADD a new value for that parameter even if one already exists.