# what is different of set vs append

Tags: javascript, urlsearchparams

In Javascript, **URLSearchParams** Is it different "set" between "append"?

```js
const test = new URLSearchParams();
test.append("name", "Harry Potter");
```

```js
const test = new URLSearchParams();
test.set("name", "Harry Potter");
```

^ different?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between the set and append methods of angulars HttpParams object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51980630/what-is-the-difference-between-the-set-and-append-methods-of-angulars-httpparams)

Comment: By append, the parameter will add whether it existed, but by set, it will add or edit if exist

Comment: To be clear should this be tagged 'Angular", and if so, which precise tag, asking for a Friend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference becomes easy to see when you call the methods twice. With `append`, both values are included in the URL, while with `set`, any present value will be overridden.

```js
const url = new URLSearchParams()
url.append("name", "Harry Potter")
url.append("name", "Hermione Granger")
url.toString() // "name=Harry+Potter&name=Hermione+Granger"
```

```js
const url = new URLSearchParams()
url.set("name", "Harry Potter")
url.set("name", "Hermione Granger")
url.toString() // "name=Hermione+Granger"
```